# How many reference points do we need for unambiguously locating other points in a space?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, metric-spaces

Let us suppose a metric spaces S with N dimensions. And let us suppose that we have a distince function d, which is able to measure the distance by any pair of point in S.

Now, let us consider that I only have a set of D distance measures between a point P and a set R of reference points. How many points the set R shoud have in order to unambiguasly locate the point P?

Intuitively, I would say that N points would be enough; one for each dimension. Am I correct?

Comment: You need $n+1$. Suppose you have two reference points in $\mathbb R^2$. Unless one of the distances is zero, the point $P$ could be at either of the intersection points of the two circles centered at $R_1$ and $R_2$.

Comment: Please, clarify your first assumption: "a metric space $S$ of dimension $N$". Are you talking about $R^N$ with the standard metric? If not, you should specify the notion of dimension.

Comment: Hi amd . Indeed, you are right!
Considering R^N is enought for me.

Comment: You need to specify the metric.  The discreet metric will never identify points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking you need one more to resolve ambiguity.  If you think about $N=2$, you have two points in $R$ and the distances from them to $P$.  You draw circles around the two points in $R$ with the appropriate radii.  Those circles intersect in two points (unless they are tangent) and you need one more distance to resolve the ambiguity.  The same thing happens in more dimensions.  If you have the same number of points as dimensions, you draw a sphere around each point and there is a finite number of intersections.  Unless you are unlucky, one more point and set of distances will resolve the question.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that you also need some linear independence conditions on $R$ to achieve this minimum.

Comment: I think you are assuming that the question is about the $N$-dimensional Euclidean space and that $R$ spans the space.

Comment: Nice! But I can chose any N+1 points, or these points should preserve some special property?

Comment: I think it is hard to state the conditions that are required.  You don't want the odd point to be the same distance from any of the intersections.  In 2D it is simple, the odd point should not be on the line between the first two points.   You have to be rather unlucky to have there still be ambiguity once you have $N+1$ points.

Comment: So, let us suppose that I am trying to locate points within a cloud of points within the space S. I think that it would be enough to select the N+1 points in the border of the cloud, in a way that each point that is selected for being included in R maximizes the distance to its nearest point in R. In this way, I think that we could avoid this. Or not?

Comment: @Zaratruta I think you can choose any $N+1$ points and have "zero" chance of ambiguity.  The scare quotes come because it can happen, but only if there is a coincidence in distances.  I would avoid three points on a line and not worry beyond that.  It gets much harder if you think there can be measurement error on the distances.  In that case there is finite volume where there is confusion and more points are better.